# Retrieving indexpath for a selected UICollectionViewCell during PreparetoSegue?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Using collectionViewCells and trying to send data via segue to the next ViewController. While getting the indexPath is not as straightforward as it is in tableViewCell, I am able to do something like this to get it, however I am still get a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

Here is the code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let cell = sender as? MainCollectionViewCell {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionview.indexPath(for: cell) {
        // use indexPath
    print(indexPath.row)
    let destvc: H1ViewController = segue.destination as! H1ViewController
  destvc.backgroundimg.image = UIImage(named: magazines[indexPath.row].image)

        }
    }

}
```

I am printing the indexpath.row and getting the value. So I am sure I am fine as far as that it is concerned. I am using if let to make sure I am not forcefully unwrapping. What can be wrong here?

Comment: For the segue.destination as! H1ViewController do an if let, so that you can see that it is of the correct type. Also try using the debugger.

Comment: Also, this happens at runtime and is certainly not a compiler-error, so I suggest removing that tag.

Comment: @Gerriet Just tried using if let on that line as well. Still nothing!

Comment: Well, what value does the error say is `nil`?

Comment: @O.Naeem , Wich one is `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` ? Add your error log

Comment: `destvc.backgroundimg` may be `nil` if it's an `IBOutlet`. Also, what triggers the `performSegueWithIdentifier()`? didSelectItem? If yes, why not sending directly the indexPath as the sender instead of the cell? Or directly the image. Another possibility, is to call `self.collection.indexPathsForSelectedItems().firstObject` to get that indexPath.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S This screenshot will help you http://imgur.com/a/p05f1

Comment: @Larme  destvc.background is an IBOutlet. When I click the cell, I am using the prepareforsegue function and using the sender as cell to give me the indexPath for that cell.

Comment: @O.Naeem, Check `magazines[indexPath.row].image` is nil or not

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S How am I supposed to check it. Sorry I have just started learning Swift.

Comment: You could do `if magazines[indexPath.row].image != nil` or you could do `if let img = magazines[indexPath.row].image` or use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this mystery. I made a string variable in destination view controller and sent string name of the images to that variable through segue. Then, in the destination view controller's ViewDidLoad method, used that string value to get the image on the imageviews IBOutlets.